# Prompt for conditional action

Tags: javascript

I was making a story but I cant get this to do what I need. I want it to perform different actions depending on whether the users types "run" or "stay" at the prompt.

```
confirm("Are You Ready To Play");
var age = prompt("How Old Are You");
if (age < 13);
{
 console.log("You Can Still Play But We Are No Responsible");
};
if (age > 13)
{ 
console.log("Great You Are At The Recommended Age");
};
console.log("You Are At A Famous Concert With Katy Perry And She starts   
singing Im Hot And Im Cold Im Yes And Im No Then She looks at You with a  
Weird Face And She like wait Stop The Music"); 
var Run = prompt("Do You Run Or Stay");    
if (Run)
{
console.log("You Run Then The Cops Are Called What Do You Do Now A Police    
Sais It's Time For Your Trial You Enter Court With a attorney But Your  
attorney failed you and you were declared GUILTY The End Try For Another  
Ending");
}
else if (Stay)
{
 console.log("We'll You Decided To Stay, well Katy perry looks At You And  
 Sais with a :) get up here and let's sing you are like WTF is happening   
 plus you get a backstage pass");
 };
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check this page so you can format your questions better next time: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help thanks @Felix for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the user input and perform the corresponding action. E.g. using a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```
var action = prompt('Do You Run Or Stay?');
switch (action.toLowerCase()) {
  case 'run': 
    // do stuff on run
    break;
  case 'stay':
    // do stuff on stay
    break;
}
```

You probably also want to think about a fallback strategy in case the user does not type either of these words.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign return value of prompt to a variable and check if the value of that variable matches to "Run" or "Stay" or something else

```
var answer = prompt("Do You Run Or Stay");    
if (answer == "Run") {
    // Run code here
}
else if (answer == "Stay") {
   // Stay code here
}
else {
   // User wrote something else
}
```